# Centre Scroll View Objects To Each Horizontal Scrolled Page - Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uiscrollview, xamarin-studio

I am doing something very similar to this, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EwSTK24IQds,
but for each object, I am placing a UI textfield. When I scroll through each page with different devices, the text does not centre to the middle of the screen. What would I have to do to make the object sit centre no matter what the device is?
The user is filling out a form and is typing in data, and scrolling to the next page for each field.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

The position of your textfield in different devices depending on your textfield's layout.

**Solution:**

For example, you add a textField to the default view of a ViewController.

I provide two methods here to center a textfield in the view no matter what the device is:

- The first is use `Frame`.You can calculate coordinates of the
  textfield in different device.
- The second is use `Autolayout`.You can add constraints to textfield to
  locate its position.

  ```
  public override void ViewDidLoad ()
  {
      base.ViewDidLoad ();
      // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

      UITextField myTextView = new UITextField();
      Add(myTextView);

      float ScreenWidth = (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
      float ScreenHeight = (float)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;

      float textFieldWidth = 200;
      float textFieldHeight = 50;

      myTextView.Text = "center myTextView";
      myTextView.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
      myTextView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue;

      //Method One:
      //Frame Center
      //myTextView.Frame = new CGRect(new CGPoint(View.Center.X-textFieldWidth/2,View.Center.Y-textFieldHeight/2), new CGSize(textFieldWidth, textFieldHeight));

      //Frame
      //myTextView.Frame = new CGRect(ScreenWidth / 2 - textFieldWidth / 2, ScreenHeight / 2 - textFieldHeight / 2, textFieldWidth, textFieldHeight);

      //Method two:
      //autolayout
      //myTextView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
      //View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(myTextView, NSLayoutAttribute.Height, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1f, textFieldHeight));
      //View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(myTextView, NSLayoutAttribute.Width, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, 1f, textFieldWidth));
      //View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(myTextView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, 1f, 10f));
      //View.AddConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint.Create(myTextView, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, 1f, 10f));

  }
  ```

Also,you can add constraints in storyboard:
[center a textfield in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgbNE.png)